# Windows Server 2008 RC2 VPN auto connect

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2

How can I make a Windows Server 2008 RC2 server, auto connect to a vpn when it boots?

Comment: It would help if you could be more specific in your question.  What is the VPN client used (Microsoft built-in, Cisco, etc.)?  Are you connecting the server in a site-to-site scenerio (where you need routing through VPN) or is the Server 2008 R2 just a client endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file/vbscript that automates a standardized VPN connection with given credentials. You can have the task run at boot so it auto starts.

If you have two factor authentication, it may be much trickier (ie: photo grid card, key chain dongle). If its the photo grid you could also code that into the batch file as static variables.

Comment: What shale i write in this batch file? it is a normal VPN with just a username and password

Comment: Honestly it depends on what VPN client your using, like the comment above, you should specify what it is you are actually using.